# Checking multiple inputs when using await in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is how my code is set up

```
async function authorizer(event, context, lambdaCallback) {
  const admin_lock = process.env.AdminLock;
  const b_authorizer = new b_Authorizer():

  const username = process.env.Username;

  await b_authorizer.isAuthorized(username, admin_lock)
    .then(isAuthorized) => {
      if (isAuthorized) {
        getDefaultPage(event, context, lambdaCallback);
      } else {
        return buildErrorResponse(....)
      }
      }
  }
```

The code works as of now. It basically checks if someone is authorized, using their username and checking the admin_lock. The thing is I also want to add a general_user_lock. And if the admin_lock results in a reject, I want to check the general_user_lock, before building the error response.

How would I go about doing this? Do I have to create another await in which the parameter is general_user_lock instead of admin_lock?

Comment: Your use of `await` mixed with `.then()` makes this a little confusing. Typically you would have something like `let isAuthorized = await b_authorizer.isAuthorized(username, admin_lock);`

Comment: So maybe I can create two variables, isAuthorizedAdmin and isAuthorizedGeneral. And then do a conditional based on those two variables?

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Try it out and if you run into any issues, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61051787/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as bellow

```
async function authorizer(event, context, lambdaCallback) {
 const admin_lock = process.env.AdminLock;
 const user_lock = process.env.UserLock; // Check whether this line is correct
 const b_authorizer = new b_Authorizer():

 const username = process.env.Username;

 const adminIsAuthorized = await b_authorizer.isAuthorized(username, admin_lock);
 const userIsAuthorized = await b_authorizer.isAuthorized(username, user_lock);

 if (adminIsAuthorized ) {
    getDefaultPage(event, context, lambdaCallback);
 } else if (userIsAuthorized) {
    // Your code if user authorized
 } else {
     return buildErrorResponse(....)
 }
}
```